# How do I send floats in window messages

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the best way to send a float in a windows message using c++ casting operators?

The reason I ask is that the approach which first occurred to me did not work. For the record I'm using the standard win32 function to send messages:

```
PostWindowMessage(UINT nMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

What does not work:

- Using `static_cast<WPARAM>()` does not work since `WPARAM` is typedef'ed to `UINT_PTR` and will do a numeric conversion from float to int, effectively truncating the value of the float.
- Using `reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>()` does not work since it is meant for use with pointers and fails with a compilation error.

I can think of two workarounds at the moment:

- Using `reinterpret_cast` in conjunction with the address of operator:

  ```
  float f = 42.0f;
  ::PostWindowMessage(WM_SOME_MESSAGE, *reinterpret_cast<WPARAM*>(&f), 0);
  ```
- Using an union:

  ```
  union { WPARAM wParam, float f };
  f = 42.0f;
  ::PostWindowMessage(WM_SOME_MESSAGE, wParam, 0);
  ```

Which of these are preffered? Are there any other more elegant way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I'd not recommend to send pointers to temporaries via something called "PostWindowMessage" since it is supposed to be asynchronous.

Comment: The pointer is dereferenced at the call (the star before the cast), no temporary address is sent to PostWindowMessage

Comment: @Kirill I'm not sending pointers to temporaries. I'm taking the address of the float, casting that address to a pointer to a WPARAM and resolving that address into a WPARAM which gets passed by value. The pointers are only used to trick the compiler into not converting the value.

Comment: @Vincent Robert, Ok, I see it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reinterpret_cast< WPARAM &>(f)`. This cast is not restricted to pointers, it also works with references.

Answer (score 2):

You could use memcpy:

```
#include <memory.h>
int main() {
    float f = 1.0;
    int n;
    memcpy( &n, &f, sizeof(f) );
}
```

I don't think there is an elegant solution to this, but whatever you do, I'd wrap it in a function to make it obvious what I was up to:

```
int FloatToInt( float f ) {
    int n;
    assert( sizeof(n) == sizeof(f) );
    memcpy( &n, &f, sizeof(f) );
    return n;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the safest way to do it. In theory using `reinterpret_cast` the way the OP does is undefined behaviour, although in practice it will probably work...

Comment: I'd add `if ( sizeof float == sizeof int )`

Comment: @Kirill I wouldn't, but I might add an assertion.

Comment: `WPARAM` is hardly a portable type. I don't think this case needs even an assertion. On Win32 and Win64, floats are no bigger than pointers, and it's entirely reasonable to assume the same for Win128.

Comment: In this answer `FloatToInt` returns `int` and not `WPARAM`.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the union. It is the clearest and easiest to understand. It also probably has the least amount of undefined behavior.

Comment: Heh, nicely put: "least amount of undefined behaviour". :P

Comment: Using the union in this way (saving in one member and reading from another) evokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Please review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22026484/4975230), type punning is defined behavior in C, but not in C++. Something like `memcpy` is probably safer than the equivalent union code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go the simple way of taking a pointer to your `float`, casting it to a pointer to `UINT`, and then dereferencing the resulting pointer:

```
WPARAM wParam = *((UINT*)(&f));
```

To convert it back you do the opposite. Doing the cast at pointer-level makes sure the compiler won't try any "conversion" behind your back.

```
float f = *((float*)(&wParam))
```

Comment: This answer is very likely to be okay, [because Visual Studio doesn't have strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176461/does-visual-c-support-strict-aliasing), but this sort of trick will fail if you try this on a compiler that supports [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) like GCC. So this is probably fine for win32, but don't make this a habit for cross platform code.