# Can you assign the value of one union member to another?

Tags: c++, memory, language-lawyer, unions

Consider the following code snippet:

```
union
{
   int a;
   float b;
};

a = /* ... */;

b = a;               // is this UB?
b = b + something;
```

Is the assignment of one union member to another valid?

Comment: I trimmed the post down a bit, I hope that's OK. Feel free to revert.

Comment: In C the answer would be that this is well defined since type punning is allowed [since C89](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c#comment26826326_2313676) in [C++ it is not as clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c). So the question here is `b = a` just considered making `b` active? Otherwise self assignment should be fine as per `1.9 p15`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Type punning seems to be ambiguous in C++. Deleted my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I wonder if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10779755/596781) is relevant somehow. Also, it would be interesting if you considered a union of user-defined types.

Comment: @KerrekSB [this conversation on WG21 UB study group mailing list](http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ub/2013-July/000083.html) seems to indicate this is very fuzzy indeed. I have to think about but I think the answer is that this is unspecified :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's more readable than before now. Thanks. English isn't my native language speaker.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65190895/1290868

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe the answer to this question is that this operation on unions is under specified in C++, although self assignment is perfectly ok.

Self assignment is well defined behavior, if we look at the draft C++ standard section `1.9` *Program execution* paragraph *15* has the following examples:

```
void f(int, int);
void g(int i, int* v) {
    i = v[i++]; // the behavior is undefined
    i = 7, i++, i++; // i becomes 9

    i = i++ + 1; // the behavior is undefined
    i = i + 1; // the value of i is incremented

    f(i = -1, i = -1); // the behavior is undefined
}
```

and self assignment is covered in the `i = i + 1` example.

The problem here is that [unlike C89 forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c#comment26826326_2313676) which supports type-punning in [C++ it is not clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310483/purpose-of-unions-in-c-and-c). We only know that:

> In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time

but as this discussion in the [WG21 UB study group mailing list](http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ub/2013-July/000083.html) shows this concept is not well understood, we have the following comments:

> While the standard uses the term "active field", it does not define it

and points out this non-normative note:

> Note: In general, one must use explicit destructor calls and placement new operators to change the active member of a union. — end note

so we have to wonder whether:

```
b = a;
```

makes `b` the active member or not? I don't know and I don't see a way to prove it with the any of the current versions of the draft standard.

Although in all practicality most modern compilers for example [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fstrict_002daliasing-881) supports type-punning in C++, which means that the whole concept of the active member is bypassed.

Comment: If the definedness of `a = b;` is not clear, then `auto x = b; a = x;` is not clear either, in my view. But clearly the latter must be OK. The Standard says that reading the right side is sequenced before the actual assignment in an expression `a = b`. So in both cases we have a sequence, and I don't see anything otherwise more critical in `a = b` (at least among the things that I could point at in the spec. Sure it "looks more critical" to me, but subject feeling doesn't count).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb are you disagreeing with the conclusion or just that I bothered to mention that self assignment is well-defined?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I don't see any type punning here; `b = a;` requests to read the `int` value of `a`, perform a conversion to `float`, and store the result in `b`. The question is whether it is undefined due to the storage of `a` and `b` overlapping. "Type punning" is the same as aliasing, it means to try and circumvent the type system by interpreting one value's representation as that of a value of different type; but that is not happening in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that unless the source and destination variables are the same type, such a thing would be Undefined Behavior in C, and I see no reason to expect C++ to handle it any differently.  Given `long long *x,*y;`, some compilers might process a statement like `*x = *y >>8;` by generating code to read all of *y, compute the result, and store it to *x, but a compiler might perfectly legitimately write code that copied parts of *y to *x individually.  The standard makes clear that if *x and *y are pointers to the same object of the same type, the compiler must ensure that no part of the value gets overwritten *while that part is still needed in the computation*, but compilers are not required to deal with aliasing in other situations.