# C++ Segmentation Fault at Union Member Assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault

The following code produces a segmentation fault upon assignment to a `union` member.  This must be a result of misunderstanding unions, but I cannot pinpoint my error.

**Q1: Is it necessary to include some initialization for the appropriate union member variables in T1's constructor?**

I have tried something similar to the suggested solution (found in code block below) to initialize the appropriate member, but no success.

**Q2: If T1 initialization is OK, why does assigning to this location produce a segmentation fault?**

#### Relevant Code:

```cpp
struct T1
{
    T1(int type)
    {
        this->type = type;
        //Q1 : need to init appropriate union struct here also? Something like:
        /*
        *if (type == 1)  
        *{
        *    union_member1.str = "";
        *}
        *else
        *{
        *    union_member2.value = 0;
        *}
        */
        //If so, better alternative to this?
    }

    int type;           //tells which union struct is used
    
    union               
    {
        struct              //type 1
        {
            std::string str;
        } union_member1;

        struct              //type 2
        {
            int value;
        } union_member2;
    };
};

struct T2
{
    bool used;
    /*
    * other variables here
    */
}; 

std::map<std::string, T2> mymap;
T1* global_ptr;

int main()
{
    for (auto& map_entry : mymap)
    {
        if (!(map_entry.second.used))
        {
            global_ptr = new T1(1);                                 
            global_ptr->union_member1.str = map_entry.first;        //Q2: SEG fault occurs with this assignment
            std::string s = map_entry.first;                        //    but not with this assignment
        }
    }
}
```

#### GDB Output

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b70b03 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Obviously, this code is shaved down for readability reasons.  Map entries have been thoroughly validated, as well.

Comment: `std::string`s are too complicated to store in a `union` unless you do a lot of extra work. `string` lives and dies by its constructor, destructor, and special member functions and by default a `union` respects none of these. Do you have access to C++17 and [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: [This answer is a bit old](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521998/4581301), but it explains the problem well and offers several potential solutions.

Comment: If anyone has a better/more up-to-date duplicate, please propose it. I'm not comfortable closing this question with a pre-C++11 duplicate that says it can't be done at all.

Comment: first question ive ever asked on here; you pointed to the problem in like 3 minutes.  thanks a ton for the help!  I am locked in c++11, however.  The use of a union was to be fancy, so I was able to move things around just a bit and no more SEG fault.  I would also be interested to see a more up to date solution to this.

Comment: With only C++11 at your disposal you can use [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/variant.html), or more likely this is some sort of assignment where you need to develop the solution yourself. In this case the keyword to search for is "tagged union". See the `struct TU`  in [the answer I linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521998/4581301). It shows how to set up everything except safe copying of the union.

Comment: Why does this segfault? No constructor is run for `union_member1`. Which means no constructor is run for `str`. `str` is just a block of uninitialized memory. It's lifetime as an object hasn't started yet. `str`'s internal buffer pointer points Zeus knows where and it's length is an uninitialized book-keeping variable containing Thor knows what value. `global_ptr->union_member1.str = map_entry.first` tries to use this horribly damaged not-yet-a-string and promptly dies for any number of perfectly valid reasons, such as trying to write into invalid memory the bad buffer pointer points at.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general-6

says that you can change the active member of a union via `u.x = ...` only if that assignment is a trivial assignment operator.  `std::string` assignment operator is not trivial, and therefore the note applies

https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general-7

> In cases where the above rule does not apply, the active member of a union can only be changed by the use of a placement new-expression.

If the string were directly a union member, you would do

```
    if (type == 1)  
    {
        new (&union_member_str) std::string();
    }
```

but it's a subobject of a union member which is an unnamed `struct` type, so you instead use placement new to construct the whole `struct` and that takes care of all its subobjects:

```
    if (type == 1)  
    {
        using UMT = decltype(union_member1);
        // or
        // typedef decltype(union_member1) UMT;
        new (&union_member1) UMT();
    }
```

Of course you will also need proper handling in copy-constructor, move-constructor, copy-assignment, move-assignment, and destructor (Rule of 5).  So much better to use an existing class such as `std::variant`.

The corresponding destructor fragment for a direct string member is

```
    if (type == 1)  
    {
        union_member_str.string::~string();
    }
```

and for your unnamed `struct` type

```
    if (type == 1)  
    {
        using UMT = decltype(union_member1);
        union_member1.UMT::~UMT();
    }
```

Don't even try to write these without a typedef / type alias.

Comment: Note: This all should work in C++11 and later

Comment: Emphasis on the word "trivial";  I.e. making all the members pointers, then it will not crash.